# How to install theme in OpenCart 3.x latest version as it is not showing header and products pages

Tags: frontend, themes, opencart-3

How to install theme in OpenCart 3.x latest version as it is not showing header and products
as I am installing a theme from Plaza Theme and I have in admin panel it's control panel slider and all settings but in frontend nothing shows instead of footer which is correctly showing please anyone facing this issue, I'm Laravel developer and new to OpenCart 3 worked with OpenCart 2
[image: About Us page not show properly opencart 3 installing theme]

[image: Look control panel is working in admin but frontend is not working]

Comment: If you are developer You should note that OC 3.x.x.x uses twig templates instead of tpl.

Comment: Yes I have worked with tpl and now it's shiffted to twig templates but I do not found solution whether how can I bring the home page ? product page etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if you are running your new theme from extensions
go to extensions->extensions->themes then enable your Theme and disable any other theme